# Adding SE OpenID to login results in page-not-found

Tags: bug, openid

When trying to add my StackExchange OpenID to my login options, it results in a page-not-found error.

Steps:

- Go to profile
- Click "My Logins"
- Click "add more logins..." (https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/login-add?returnUrl=%2Fusers%2Fcurrent)
- Click "More login options"
- Copy and paste the guid url (https://openid.stackexchange.com/user/{guid-here}) into the text box or the normal url (https://openid.stackexchange.com/) or the listed provider url (https://openid.stackexchange.com/openid/provider) which is a 404 in itself.
- Press submit
- Arrive on https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/authenticate which is a 404 page.