# Can't add new Stack Exchange openid login

Tags: support, login, accounts, openid

I'm trying to get away from google login so I created a new Stack Exchange openid login. I then went to my Stack Overflow profile, logins page, and selected add more logins. In the box where you can enter your own openid, I tried both the vanity url and the url it gives me when I click "use your own url to login". Both bring me to a page asking me to confirm, and when I click confirm, I'm returned to my Stack Overflow profile, and the login is not added. What am I doing wrong?

I tried [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/793/how-do-i-change-my-openid-providers/114704#114704), didn't work, <s>but now my gravatar is missing too, yay.</s> Gravatar fixed.

Comment: Have you logged out of Google? It might be picking up that you're already logged into Google and therefore don't need to use the SE OpenID.

Comment: The issue is with adding a new login, since it's supposed to support multiple logins as far as I understand. I haven't gotten to the point of trying to login with the new account because I can't add it yet

Comment: Have you tried this again recently? Or checked to see if maybe your login list just updated slowly? (I'm assuming by your comment about not trying to login with it yet that you mean the login is not added to your list of logins.)

Comment: [Try this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/793/how-do-i-change-my-openid-providers/114704#114704)... If that work around doesn't work, then update your post

Comment: @Kendra Correct, the new login is not being added so I can't login with it. I just tried to add it again, same issue.

Comment: @psubsee2003 Didn't work

Comment: Afaik this is broken for months. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285667/adding-se-openid-to-login-results-in-page-not-found?rq=1

Comment: @Sumurai8 Your issue from that post is you were going through MSO and not regular SO (Not saying it's not a bug, but if it isn't, then they should remove that option from MSO.) Try doing it again from the SO main site, if you haven't already. ConditionRacer, are you trying this from SO main, or from here on Meta, just wondering?

Comment: @Kendra from stackoverflow

Comment: Then the best I can say at this point is you'll have to wait for a developer/team member to step in and keep trying things others suggest.